# Wordpress - sub page link reverts to Home page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a site on Wordpress and using html5blank theme for the first time. I have a number of sub-pages I need to add as links from one of the main pages.

On of my main pages is titled 'Agency' and within the agency page I have a number of images which act as links to a number (7) of sub-pages -

[image: Images / Links]

I've created the sub-pages on my dashboard with Agency as the parent so the link I get for the first image is ...site-name/agency/2k4kproduction . Here's the code for the links. So far I've only converted two of the links (2k4k and adhoc) -

```
<div class="twelve columns agencyproducts">
                            <p>WHAT PRODUCT ARE YOU INTERESTED IN?</p>
                    <a href="http://localhost:8888/agency/2k4k-production/"><figure>
                        <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/production.png" alt="Production">
                        <figcaption>2K / 4K PRODUCTION</figcaption>
                    </figure></a>
                    <a href="postproduction.html"><figure>  
                        <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/post-production.png" alt="Post-Production">
                        <figcaption>POST PRODUCTION</figcaption>
                    </figure></a>
                    <a href="2d3danimation.html"><figure>
                        <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/animation.png" alt="Animation">
                        <figcaption>2D / 3D ANIMATION</figcaption>
                    </figure></a>
                    <a href="http://localhost:8888/agency/adhoc/"><figure>   
                        <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/ADHOC.png" alt="ADHOC">
                        <figcaption>ADHOC</figcaption>
                    </figure></a>
                    <a href="interactive.html"><figure> 
                        <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/interactive.png" alt="Interactive">
                        <figcaption>INTERACTIVE & PERSONALISED</figcaption>
                    </figure></a>
                    <a href="tvadverts.html"><figure>
                        <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/tv-adverts.png" alt="TV ADVERTS">
                        <figcaption>TV ADVERTS</figcaption>
                    </figure></a>
                    <a href="360video.html"><figure>    
                        <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/360.png" alt="360 Video and VR">
                        <figcaption>360 VIDEO & VIRTUAL REALITY</figcaption>
                    </figure></a>   
                </div>
```

For my text files I've titled them page-agency-2k4kproduction.php and page-agency-adhoc.php which is what I believed to be the correct naming convention as per the template hierarchy. However, when I click on these links they revert to my home page. I've no idea why this is not working as my agency file/page works fine as page-agency.php so I'm not sure why this will not work. Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: If the sub-page has the same layout as the parent page, there's no reason to add a different template, just let it use `page.php`

Comment: Maybe the problem come from the permalinks, try to change settings with the default option `http://www.sample.com/?p=123`

Comment: @APAD1 I've tried it both ways - page-parent-child.php and as page-child.php and in both circumstances the page doesn't load, it just clicks back to page.php (my home page).

Comment: You don't need `page-parent-child.php` or `page-child.php` just let it use `page.php`. Your homepage should be using `index.php`

Comment: @APAD1 So just child.php then?

Comment: No..... `page.php`

Comment: @APAD1 You'll have to excuse my naivety here but everything I'm reading and seeing suggests that it should be page-parent-child.php. I've already created a number of pages with page-slug.php and they've worked, I don't understand why page-parent-child.php wouldn't work. Also, if I have multiple sub pages how does the right one get selected??

Comment: The only reason you would need to make different templates is if the child pages are going to have a different layout. If you just want your pages to have a header/footer with the page content in the middle you only need `page.php`

Comment: @APAD1 I think I'm going to edit this question because I don't think I'm getting across what the specific issue is. Either way its not working - I don't understand what you mean re page.php - surely this would mean I could have , say, 10 or 11 page.php files in my folder? How does it know which page goes with which link?

Comment: You have one single `page.php` template file and then the 10 or 11 pages all use the same template file. You're not supposed to make a different template file for each individual page, that completely eliminates the purpose of using a CMS or PHP for that matter.

Comment: @APAD1 I've updated the question. I'm quite new to Wordpress (can you tell?) having just come over from RoR and am having a hard time getting my head around this. Surely I need to put an identifier on the file to link it to the page?

Comment: Nope, all pages use the `page.php` template file by default, no identifiers needed. Whatever page you have set as the "front page" in Settings>Reading will use the `index.php` template file. This is all documented pretty well in the [Wordpress Theme Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/).

Comment: @APAD1 So what does the handbook mean then when it refers to page-{slug}.php ? This is the convention I used when naming the agency page file page-agency.php and it worked.

Comment: @APAD1 I've just changed my home page from page.php to index.php and now nothing shows up when I launch the main page. I already had the settings changed as you explain above.